# How to get UIView / Menu to slide in and slide out? (Xamarin IOS using C# Not Swift)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

ive attached rough draft images of what im trying to do. basically push that menu button, the menu (yellow) appears, push it again and it goes away. but it just jumps out, and i would like it to slide out and in, in an animated fashion. all the libraries and resources i've found on this tend to use swift. any way to do this using IOS that is recommendable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code about  push the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `CoreAnimation`.Change `Frame` of menu in some seconds.Refer the following code

> push out the menu

```
UIView.Animate(0.8, () =>
  {
    CGRect outRect= new CGRect(0, menuView.Frame.Y, menuView.Frame.Width, menuView.Frame.Height);
    menuView.Frame = pushRect;
  });
```

> push in the menu

```
UIView.Animate(0.8, () =>
  {
    CGRect inRect = new CGRect(20- menuView.Frame.Width, menuView.Frame.Y, menuView.Frame.Width, menuView.Frame.Height);
    menuView.Frame = inRect;
  });
```

0.8 in the durtaion of the Animation.